# Stepfunction map with condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Is there is any possibility to run the was step function map Iterator based on the condition Am going to invoke the lambda and based on the result I have to choose the input item of the iteration meaning if there is an array of 0-3 items once the first item executes with lambda then based on the result it should execute  1st index or 2nd index item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option is to create a while loop like this:

- Set a variable to track your index (pos = 0)
- Do whatever you want to do inside your iteration also you could use some condition, if you want to process each item conditionally
- increase your index ( pos++)
- If your index is less that your items count go to step1.

This way you have access to the result of previous iteration, so you can fine tune your condition.

Comment: Thanks @Pooya Paridel I will try it out. Your answer is similar to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html